# FLEX - Disable spacebar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, tabnavigator

I've got an application, which is tabbed (using TabNavigator).

When it starts, I switch tab to nr.2 (default is tab 1). I need to be able to hold down spacebar and drag the mouse to pan, but when I do this it switches back to the first tab. So the spacebar is triggering it to switch.

I've tried using a custom lass that extends tabNavigator, like the code below, but it's not working. Also tried setting focusEnabled = false without luck.

Any idea how I would solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Stian Berg Larsen

```
package components
{
import mx.containers.TabNavigator;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

public class myTabNavigator extends TabNavigator
{
    public function myTabNavigator()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected override function keyDownHandler(e : KeyboardEvent) : void {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) { // Spacebar
            return;
        }
        super.keyDownHandler(e);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably caused because you are not stopping your event from bubbling.

Try this:

```
protected override function keyDownHandler(e : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) { // Spacebar
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }
    super.keyDownHandler(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow it works now with the code I posted above... Strange..
Also, I'm suddenly getting error: Out of memory.. Trying to solve it..